# Django can't populate table rows on loop every x seconds with jquery post

Tags: django

I want to repopulate my table every few seconds to see what clients are doing on our servers. I'm new to Django but I've managed to stand this project up on a remote server through SSL. I need to request this information and then send back the list for table. I've gotten 404 forbidden errors, errors related to not being able to find the function, ect. Currently, I have the information being fetched but its refreshing the entire page rather than the table rows.

This is obviously because I was using:

```
**setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('jobs').submit()
}, 5000);**
```

Which I'm trying to avoid

**Views.py (part of it)**

```
class ActiveServerJobsView(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'project_name/active_server_jobs.html'
    context_object_name = 'current_job_list'
    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            db_default = connections['default']
            default_cursor = db_default.cursor()
            default_cursor.execute("select server_name from table_name where server_is_database = True")
            host_list = default_cursor.fetchall()
            current_job_list = get_current_jobs(host_list)
            args = {'current_job_list': current_job_list}
            return render(request,'project_name/active_server_jobs.html',args)
    def get_queryset(self):
        db_default = connections['default']
        default_cursor = db_default.cursor()
        default_cursor.execute("select junk, and, stuff from table_name where server_is_database = True")
        host_list = default_cursor.fetchall()
        return get_current_jobs(host_list)
def get_current_jobs(host_list):
    current_jobs = []
    for host in host_list:
        host_name = host[0]
        host_db = connections[host_name + "/example"]
        host_cursor = host_db.cursor()
        #get file jobs
        host_cursor.execute("select junk, and, stuff")
        host_file_list = host_cursor.fetchall()
        for host_file in host_file_list:
            junk, and, stuff = host_file
            current_jobs.append(something))
        #get report jobs
        host_cursor.execute("select junk, and, stuff")
        host_file_list = host_cursor.fetchall()
        for host_file in host_file_list:
            junk, and, stuff = host_file
            current_jobs.append(Current_Jobs_On_Server.create(junk, and, stuff))
    return current_jobs
```

**template/project_name/active_server_jobs.html**

```js
        setInterval(function() {
         document.getElementById('jobs').submit()
        }, 5000);
```

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load app_filters %}
<html>
{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'project_name/template/index_style.css' %}">
<body>
<div id="header">


</div>
<center class="container" style="margin-top: 5%;">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
   <h1 class="panel-title"><strong>Working Jobs</strong></h1>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
 <div  style="overflow: auto;">
 <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y">
         <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
             <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th scope="col">#</th>
                 <th scope="col">Server</th>
   <th scope="col">junktitle</th>
   <th scope="col">junktitle</th>
   <th scope="col">junktitle</th>
   <th scope="col">junktitle</th>
   <th scope="col">junktitle</th>
   <th scope="col">junktitle</th>
   <th scope="col">junktitle</th>
   <th scope="col">junktitle</th>
             </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
  <form id="jobs" action="active_server_jobs" method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
   {% if current_job_list %}
       {% for job in current_job_list %}
   <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
    <th>{{job.junk}}</td>
    <td>{{job.junk1}}</td>
    <td>{{job.junk2}}</td>
    <td>{{job.junk3}}
    <td>{{job.junk4}}</td>
    <td>{{job.junk5}}</td>
    <td>{{job.junk6}}</td>
    <td>{{job.junk7}}</td>
    <td>{{job.junk8}}</td>
   </tr> 

       {% endfor %}
   {% else %}
   <h3><strong>There are currently no working jobs</strong></h3>
   {% endif %}
  </form>
  </tbody>
         </table>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</center>
</body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! I'm amazed I've gotten this far but I'm now stumped on an ajax request SMH

Comment: Why aren't you using the ORM? You look to be doing simple queries where the Django ORM shines.

Comment: I'm reading a tutorial now but could you please elaborate on how I would refactor what I have now?

Comment: I use ORM here Audit_Log.objects.all() in a different view. I didn't use it for this particular view class because I'm querying databases from multiple servers

Comment: I would like to add that the ORM is not being used for this particular queryset because I have to do an inner join without a foreign key relationship on tables not on this server. I'm still stumped on this issue related to post backs. The only comment I've received does not have anything to do with my problem that I'm aware of